# How can I skip JRE-java code when debugging in **Intellij-idea**?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

How can I skip JRE -- Java code -- when debugging in **IntelliJ-Idea**?
In Eclipse, the debug filters function well. But, with IntelliJ I am struggling.  Any help please?

Answer (score 3):

Settings -> Debugging -> Do not step into classes

add proper class prefixes in

Comment: Thank you very much; it works but still not very well. 
If the <Force Step Into> being pressed once, the rest stepping will go through the JRE -- Java code – in all other stepping types.

Comment: Is there a way to reuse  skip  JRE code  after using <Force Step Into>, in case of IntelliJ-Idea DE? I tried to find  related setting but got nothing. Maybe it is a small bug

Comment: You mean once you press F7 to go into the JRE code... it continue to do so? If that's the case I think that;s how the IDE works if you go into the JRE code because you want to see what's going on inside, then it continues. But if you press F7 in your code base and it causes to go into the JRE code base it sounds lie a bug. Which version are you using?